# confused about the use of the

Tags: grammar, articles

This is the first sentence of an introductory paragraph

> Translation of scientific texts has a long history in North Africa.

Does it sound right? Should it be:

> *The* translation of scientific texts has a long history in North Africa.

Could you please explain why it should or should not be used here?

Comment: I agree with you. The version with the added *the* sounds better.

Comment: The second sentence implies that we are talking about translations that have already been mentioned previously.

Comment: @Nate but as I mentioned before this is the first sentence of an introductory paragraph. Do you think the sentence without _the_ sounds better here? I don't know why it sounds awkward to me.

Comment: THE essesntially means "THAT instance of what you, my dear listener, and I are talking about, that you are perceiving as we speak—and I know you are, coz I can see it in your mind, I'm looking right at it. You are able to instantiate it because you know what class of thing it is, and you know it either because you have been partaking in the collective knowledge of our relevant community (exophoric reference) or because I've just a moment ago painted you a picture of it (anaphoric ref.), or because I've just signalled you that I'm about to paint it and you're anticipating it (cataphoric r.)"

Comment: in 'Translation of scientific texts has a long history in North Africa.' no instantiation can possibly be made, becuase the speaker's intention is to reference not an element of the class (a 'set' for the mathematically inclined) called "TRANSLATION (of something)" a.k.a. "TRANSLATING (something)", but rather to reference the entire class. It doesn't matter at all whether the picture of the thing is already in the listener's mind (via 1 of the 3 types of referencing). The speaker wants to direct the listener's attention to the whole class per se, and English grammar capacitates him to do that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't understand it as being a stylistic choice. It's a semantic choice, not aesthetic.

Comment: @TaliaFord so grammatically speaking both sentences are correct?

Comment: Yes. They have a different meaning though.

Comment: @Talia: I think you're trying to make a distinction based on a literal interpretation that simply doesn't apply in OP's example. Both versions are normal English, and both mean *exactly* the same thing. So far as I can see, there's simply no scope for postulating that including the definite article somehow makes a *semantic* difference. It can only refer to *translation of scientific texts* in general, not any particular translation. If you like, you can say *the* specifically refers to translations made *in Africa*, but that's what they are in both versions anyway - no change in meaning.

Comment: The nearest equivalent construction I can easily chart is *[He said] [that **{the}** use of illegal](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+use+of+illegal%2Cthat+the+use+of+illegal&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) [drugs was a scourge on society]*, which accords with my gut feeling that we *do* normally include the article, but that may be changing in more recent decades.

Comment: @rery Yes, I would prefer the first sentence merely because here you don't **need** the article "*the*". It's like using parentheses in a mathematical expression: If the expression is (2+2)x2, parentheses are **necessary**, because the result is different from 2+2x2 ([more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)). But if the expression is 2+(2+2), parentheses are **unnecessary** yet not *unacceptable*. The result would be the same as 2+2+2. In the same way, the article "*the*" is unnecessary in your sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence could be correct if you use "Gerund" for like:

> **Translating scientific texts has a long history in North Africa.**

Otherwise you should use the second sentence.